# Split revenue by year with Google Sheets' QUERY function

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query

I get monthly revenue data from the finance department that I have clean to input into a reporting format. Its monthly data that lists all revenue in a single column. I need to split out the revenue by years (2018, 2019, etc.).

I believe that I need to use a query function for this but if you have some other solution, then I'm open to that too.

The data looks like this:

```
Client  Source         Month    Year    Revenue
abc     Google             1    2019    100
abc     Google             1    2018    100
abc     Facebook           1    2018    50
abc     Facebook           2    2018    50
```

And I need it to look like this:

```
Client  Source        Month 2018 Revenue    2019 Revenue
abc     Google          1     100           100
abc     Facebook        1     50            0
abc     Facebook        2     50            0
```

I'm familiar with query functions but I can't wrap my head around how to do this.

The pseudo code for this would be something like:

```
select Client, 
       Source, 
       Month,  
       Case when Year in 2019 then sum(Revenue) as 2019 Revenue else 0 end,
       Case when Year in 2018 then sum(Revenue) as 2018 Revenue else 0 end

from   Data

Group  by Client, Source, Month
```

Please let me know if I need to provide any additional information. And I appreciate your help with this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=QUERY(A1:E, "select A,B,C,sum(E) where A is not null group by A,B,C pivot D", 1)
```

[image: 9]

Comment: Wow thanks for this! i had no idea the pivot function existed in query